# Join List Adds Separator to Each Character NOT Each List Item

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list structure returned from a function:

```
[[0, 'bss', 0, 'ssid']]
```

I'm trying to join the list elements with a forward slash:

```
        for i in range(0, len(self.result)):
        if isinstance(self.result[i], list):
            print('Found a list')
            print(self.result[i])
            print('Joining list ...')
            ncos_path = '/'.join(str(self.result[i]))
            print(ncos_path)
            for j in range(0, len(self.result[i])):
                print('List item = {}'.format(self.result[i][j]))
```

This results in the output

```
[[0, 'bss', 0, 'ssid']]
Found a list
[0, 'bss', 0, 'ssid']
Joining list ...
[/0/,/ /'/b/s/s/'/,/ /0/,/ /'/s/s/i/d/'/]
List item = 0
List item = bss
List item = 0
List item = ssid
```

I'm not understanding why the join operation doesn't result in

```
'0/bss/0/ssid'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `join` operation here

```
>>> l = [[0, 'bss', 0, 'ssid']]
>>>
>>> l = ['/'.join(str(i) for i in j) for j in l]
>>> l
['0/bss/0/ssid']
```

why you are getting `[/0/,/ /'/b/s/s/'/,/ /0/,/ /'/s/s/i/d/'/]` as output? because `str(self.result[i])`  converting list to string enirely, not individual inner elements `[0, 'bss', 0, 'ssid']` the  `"[0, 'bss', 0, 'ssid']"`.

ie. first  `str(self.result[i])` become `"[0, 'bss', 0, 'ssid']"`
and when you join operation on this string then join operation convert it to/consider it as list of characters , and then joining all character by `/`  and giving you output you are getting

Comment: Facepalm!  Thank you!  I was converting to string because the list contains integers and obviously did it the wrong way!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than applying `str` to each element within `self.results[i]`, you are applying str to the entire sublist. To get your desired behavior, a simple list comprehension would suffice:

```
"/".join([str(item) for item in results[i]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting a list into a string. Trying to join members of the converted list object like this `str(result[i])` won't work as you expected.

Note that in Python strings behaves like a `list` of characters. Indeed, the `str` type extends sequences like: `list`, `tuple`, `range`

Python documentation:

> Strings implement all of the common sequence operations
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

`'/'.join('example')`, the expected value is `'e/x/a/m/p/l/e'`.
Why ? Because `'example'` is an object instance of type `str`, which extends the sequences types like `list`. 
Also, `.join()` is a method of a `str` instances and takes an `iterable` as argument. `example` is a `str` which behaves like a sequence which implements the iterable operations.

Solution example: (should run as is)

```
result = [[0, 'bss', 0, 'ssid']]
for i in range(0, len(result)):
    if isinstance(result[i], list):
        print('Found a list')
        print(result[i])
        print('Joining list ...')
        ncos_path = '/'.join(str(x) for x in result[i])
        print(ncos_path)
        for j in range(0, len(result[i])):
            print('List item = {}'.format(result[i][j]))
```

Output:

```
"Found a list
[0, 'bss', 0, 'ssid']
Joining list ...
0/bss/0/ssid
List item = 0
List item = bss
List item = 0
List item = ssid"
```